# Group by and Case when SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, case

I have a table containing the date , the phone number , the name , and the sale amount. I want to apply the condition on the name and if the name initial letter is "X" then put the second two letters of name else trim the first letter and run the below query, but it is not working.

Here is my SQL code that is not working. I appreciate it if someone helps me.

```
SELECT
    Date, phone_number, SUM(sale), 
    CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1) = 'X' 
            THEN SUBSTRING(name, 1, 2) 
            ELSE SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1) 
    END AS Initailname
FROM
    table_1 
GROUP BY
    Date, phone_number, SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1)
```

Comment: "Not working" will not help us help you. Not working how???  Wrong result? No result?  Error out?

Comment: In some DBMS, you could simply change your group by to `group by 1,2,4` or even `group by Date, phone_number, Initailname`.  In other DBMS, you may need to repeat the entire case expression in the group by.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` don't match. Putting date and phone number aside, you want one result row per initial. So there will be one result row for all names starting with 'X' for instance. But in your `SELECT` list you say you want to show the first *two* characters of the name starting with 'X'. What is that second character? 'A'? 'B'? There can be many different characters, so the DBMS tells you that you forgot to tell it which character you want to see in an 'X' result row.

Make sure that besides any aggreagtions (`SUM`, `COUNT`, etc.) you only select what you have in your `GROUP BY` clause.

One approach is this:

```
WITH prepared_data AS
(
  SELECT
    date,
    phone_number,
    CASE WHEN ... END AS initialname,
    sale
  FROM table_1
)
SELECT date, phone_number, initialname, SUM(sale)
FROM prepared_data
GROUP BY date, phone_number, initialname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your GROUP BY statement is invalid. The proper syntax would depend on your DBMS. SQL Server does not respect a case expression alias; therefore you must use the entire case expression. Other DBMS such as Postgres or MySQL offers multiple variations.

```
create table table_1 (
  date date, 
  phone_number varchar(10), 
  name varchar(10), 
  sale integer
  );

insert into table_1 values 
('2023-01-01', '5554443333', 'AABA', 20), 
('2023-01-01', '5554443333', 'AABB', 30), 
('2023-01-02', '5554443333', 'AABC', 10), 
('2023-01-01', '5554443333', 'XABA', 20), 
('2023-01-01', '5554443333', 'XBBB', 30), 
('2023-01-01', '5554443333', 'XBBC', 10);
```

```
--Repeating case expression in group by (needed for SQL Server)
select date, phone_number, sum(sale), 
  case
   when substring(name, 1, 1) = 'X' then substring(name, 1, 2) 
   else substring(name, 1, 1)
  end as Initailname
from table_1
group by date, phone_number, 
 case
   when substring(name, 1, 1) = 'X' then substring(name, 1, 2) 
   else substring(name, 1, 1)
  end
order by 4,1
```

| date | phone_number | sum | initailname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 5554443333 | 50 | A |
| 2023-01-02 | 5554443333 | 10 | A |
| 2023-01-01 | 5554443333 | 20 | XA |
| 2023-01-01 | 5554443333 | 40 | XB |

```
--Postgres, MySQL and many others
select date, phone_number, sum(sale), 
  case
   when substring(name, 1, 1) = 'X' then substring(name, 1, 2) 
   else substring(name, 1, 1)
  end as Initailname
from table_1
group by 1,2,4
order by 4,1
```

| date | phone_number | sum | initailname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 5554443333 | 50 | A |
| 2023-01-02 | 5554443333 | 10 | A |
| 2023-01-01 | 5554443333 | 20 | XA |
| 2023-01-01 | 5554443333 | 40 | XB |

```
--Postgres, MySQL and many others
select date, phone_number, sum(sale), 
  case
   when substring(name, 1, 1) = 'X' then substring(name, 1, 2) 
   else substring(name, 1, 1)
  end as Initailname
from table_1
group by date, phone_number, initailname
order by 4,1
```

| date | phone_number | sum | initailname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 5554443333 | 50 | A |
| 2023-01-02 | 5554443333 | 10 | A |
| 2023-01-01 | 5554443333 | 20 | XA |
| 2023-01-01 | 5554443333 | 40 | XB |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/udVR-uFc)

Comment: Note as you mention SQL Server you can easily workaround this by implementing the case expression in an `apply()` then you can reference it both in the `select` and `group by`

Comment: @Stu, thanks, good to know. I haven't used this DBMS in ages and quite unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 0):

As per your statement -

*"if the name initial letter is "X" then put the second two letters of name else trim the first letter"*

It seems you need the below query -

```
select date, phone_number, sum(sale), 
       case when substring(name, 1, 1) = 'X' then substring(name, 2, 2) 
            else substring(name, 2)
       end as Initailname
  from table_1
 group by date, phone_number,
          case when substring(name, 1, 1) = 'X' 
                    then substring(name, 2, 2) 
               else substring(name, 2)
          end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
Date,
phone_number,
SUM(sale) AS total_sale,
CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1) = 'X' THEN SUBSTRING(name, 2, 2)
    ELSE SUBSTRING(name, 2, LEN(name))
END AS Initialname
FROM
    table_1
GROUP BY
    Date,
    phone_number,
    CASE
        WHEN SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1) = 'X' THEN SUBSTRING(name, 1, 2)
        ELSE SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1)
    END;
```

Answer (score -1):

- if the name initial letter is "X"

  - then put the second two letters of name
  - else trim the first letter

```
SELECT
  [date], 
  phone_number, 
  SUM(sale),
  substring(name,case when left(name,1)='X' then 2 else 1 end,case when left(name,1)='X' then 2 else 1 end) as initial
FROM table_1
GROUP BY
  [date], 
  phone_number,
  substring(name,case when left(name,1)='X' then 2 else 1 end,case when left(name,1)='X' then 2 else 1 end)
```

output  (sample data borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/77011430/724039):

| date | phone_number | (No column name) | initial |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 5554443333 | 50 | A |
| 2023-01-01 | 5554443333 | 20 | AB |
| 2023-01-01 | 5554443333 | 40 | BB |
| 2023-01-02 | 5554443333 | 10 | A |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/96ehUm_G)

Another way of getting the same result, is using a common table expression:

```
WITH cte AS (
   select 
      [date],phone_number, name, sale, 
      substring(name,case when left(name,1)='X' then 2 else 1 end,case when left(name,1)='X' then 2 else 1 end) as initial
   from table_1
  )
SELECT
  [date], 
  phone_number, 
  SUM(sale),
  initial
FROM cte
GROUP BY
  [date], 
  phone_number,
  initial
```